# Ranges that act as filters - different set of iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I would like to iterate over customized ranges like that:

```
for(auto &all : data.getAll())
    for(auto odd : data.getOdds())
        for(auto X : data.getX())
           ...
```

I know that range-based loops use iterators and thus one needs to specialize begin(), end().
[Is there a cleaner method than this one](http://ideone.com/AD8X49)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/range/adaptor/) of [Boost.Range Adaptors](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html). There are several [named adaptors](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference.html) that overload `operator|` to perform operations like filtering, transformation etc. of the input range.

```
std::vector<int> vec(20);
std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);

using namespace boost::adaptors;

for(auto i : vec | filtered([](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; })
                 | transformed([](int i){ return i * 2; })
                 | reversed) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

The above example prints only even numbers from the input range after doubling them, and reversing the resulting range.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d27e05009ae4e0a6)

Comment: They look amazing but I can't use boost.

Comment: @name You could look through the [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/range/adaptor/) for ideas on how to go about reinventing them yourself.

Comment: @Praetorian I am doing just that ;-)